# DataGridView and List<T> and sorting

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, datagridview

I want to sort my DataGridView.
I tried this:

```
Grid.DataSource = PlayerList;
Grid.Refresh();
```

and this:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = PlayerList;
Grid.DataSource = bs;
```

Every time I get an error saying:

> DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted.

What do I need to do to get it working?

Comment: What methods you have used to sort the `List<T>` or `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to implement `IBindingList` then use `List<T>` Sort method.

```
 PlayerList.Sort((p,q) => {
                     if (p.Age >= q.Age)
                            return 1;
                        else
                            if (p.Age < q.Age)
                                return -1;
                        return 0;
                    });
    Grid.DataSource = PlayerList;
```

Comment: What if I want to be able to sort based on difrent properties of Player class? For example. Age, Sex, Town, Weapon?

Comment: @Hooch - Is it possible to convert List<T> to DataTable. DataTable uses DataView (IBindingList is implemented by DataView)) that allow you to sort on any expression (column) without any extra code.